# Select, count and where using codeigniter and mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have two table as follow:

```
- tblSaler

    SalerID  |  SalerName | 
    ----------------------|
    1        |  sothorn   |
    ----------------------|
    2        |  Daly      |  
    ----------------------|
    3        |  Lyhong    |
    ----------------------|
    4        | Chantra    |
    ----------------------|

- tblProduct

ProductID  | Product  | SalerID |
--------------------------------|
1          | Pen      | 3       |
--------------------------------|
2          | Book     | 2       |
--------------------------------|
3          | Phone    | 3       |
--------------------------------|
4          | Computer | 1       |
--------------------------------|
5          | Bag      | 3       |
--------------------------------|
6          | Watch    | 2       |
--------------------------------|
7          | Glasses  | 4       |
--------------------------------|
```

The result that I need is:

```
sothorn | 1
Daly    | 2
Lyhong  | 3
Chantra | 1
```

I have tried this :

```
    $this->db->select('count(SalerName) as sothorn where tblSaler.SalerID = 1, count(SalerName) as Daly where tblSaler.SalerID = 2, count(SalerName) as Lyhong where tblSaler.SalerID = 3, count(SalerName) as Chantra where tblSaler.SalerID = 4');
    $this->db->from('tblSaler');
    $this->db->join('tblProduct', 'tblSaler.SalerID = tblProduct.SalerID');
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use this query for this

```
SELECT
  tblSaler.SalerName,
  count(tblProduct.ProductID) as Total
FROM tblSaler
  LEFT JOIN tblProduct
    ON tblProduct.SalerID = tblSaler.SalerID
GROUP BY tblSaler.SalerID
```

And here is the active record for this

```
$select =   array(
                'tblSaler.SalerName',
                'count(tblProduct.ProductID) as Total'
            );  
$this->db
        ->select($select)
        ->from('tblSaler')
        ->join('tblProduct','Product.SalerID = tblSaler.SalerID','left')
        ->group_by('tblSaler.SalerID')
        ->get()
        ->result_array();
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8dcf/1)

OUTPUT

```
_____________________
| SALERNAME | TOTAL |
|-----------|-------|
|   sothorn |     1 |
|      Daly |     2 |
|    Lyhong |     3 |
|   Chantra |     1 |
_____________________
```

Answer (score 4):

Please try this code. Its working fine for me and it will help you also.

```
$this->db->select('SalerName, count(*)');
$this->db->from('tblSaler');        
$this->db->join('tblProduct', 'tblSaler.SalerID = tblProduct.SalerID'); 
$this->db->group_by('tblSaler.SalerID');       
$query = $this->db->get();
```

You can get whole SQL query using this line below

```
$query = $this->db->get(); 
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This

```
$this->db->select('SalerName, count(*)'); 
$this->db->from('tblSaler'); 
$this->db->join('tblProduct', 'tblSaler.SalerID = tblProduct.SalerID');
$this->db->group('SalerID');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   ## try this ##
   $this->db->select($column_name);
    $this->db->where($column_name,$type);
    $q=$this->db->get($table_name);
    $count=$q->result();
    return count($count);'
```