# count only one selected data with where clause

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I have model like this :

```
    function getAll()
  {
    $this->db->select('tbl_keluarga.no_kk,tbl_keluarga.id_keluarga,
    tbl_keluarga.koordinat,
    tbl_penduduk.nama,
    tbl_penduduk.id_penduduk,
    count(tbl_hub_kel.id_keluarga) as jumlah,
    count(tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga) as anak,
    tbl_hasil_sensus.status')->from('tbl_keluarga');
    $this->db->join('tbl_penduduk','tbl_penduduk.id_penduduk = tbl_keluarga.id_kepala_keluarga');
    $this->db->join('tbl_hasil_sensus','tbl_hasil_sensus.id_keluarga = tbl_keluarga.id_keluarga');
    $this->db->join('tbl_hub_kel','tbl_hub_kel.id_keluarga = tbl_keluarga.id_keluarga');

    $this->db->group_by('tbl_keluarga.id_keluarga');
    $this->db->order_by('tbl_hub_kel.id_keluarga');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    return $q->result(); 
  }
```

How can I set where clause only for count(tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga) as anak

thank you for helping me

Comment: so when I set where clause, it change the value from another selected count

Comment: Try this maybe it will help you
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19628783/4141247

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->join('tbl_hub_kel','tbl_hub_kel.id_keluarga = tbl_keluarga.id_keluarga AND tbl_hub_kel.id_status_keluarga={status_value}');
```

Try this hope it will work.

Comment: not solved, the value still changed example : before where clause value = 4 , after where clause value = 2