# implemented counting data before insert using CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm making a OffDayWork form, which I expect that every employee only can request their off-day-work maximum of 12 times. I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627475/select-count-and-where-using-codeigniter-and-mysql) as my reference, but it still has not worked.

This is my structure table :

```
- tabel_cuti

    holID | holEmpId | holName |
    ---------------------------| 
    1     | 1        | Ied     | 
    ---------------------------| 
    2     | 3        | exp1    | 
    ---------------------------| 
    3     | 4        | exp2    | 
    ---------------------------| 
    4     | 1        | Married | 
    ---------------------------|
```

I tried this in my model

- EmployeeModel

  ```
  public function HolidayRegister($data)
  {
      $this->db->insert('tbl_cuti',$data);
      return true;
  }

  public function HitungCuti($data)
  {       
  $this->db->select('count(table_cuti.holID) as countcuti');
  $this->db->from('tabel_cuti');
  $this->db->join('tabel_pegawai','tabel_cuti.holEmpId = tabel_pegawai.empID');
  $this->db->group_by('table_cuti.holEmpId');
  $totalhol = $this->db->get();
  }
  ```

And my controller (Employee)

```
public function HolidayRegister()
    {
        if(!empty($_POST))
        {
            $data =  array('holEmpId' => $this->input->post('employee_id'),
                    'holName' => $this->input->post('holiday_name'),
                    'holDate' => $this->input->post('holiday_date'),
                    'holDescription' => $this->input->post('description'),
                    'created_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    );
            $result = $this->EmployeeModel->HitungCuti($data);

            if($result -> num_rows() < 12)
            {
                $this->EmployeeModel->HolidayRegister($data);
            }
            else
            {
                $data =  array('holEmpId' => $this->input->post('employee_id'),
                    'holName' => $this->input->post('holiday_name'),
                    'holDate' => $this->input->post('holiday_date'),
                    'holDescription' => $this->input->post('description'),
                    'created_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    );
                $this->session->set_flashdata('SUCCESSMSG','Tidak ada kesempatan cuti');
                $data['getEmployee'] = $this->EmployeeModel->getEmployee();
                $this->load->view('holiday_register',$data);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('SUCCESSMSG', "Holiday Register Successfully!!");
            redirect('view-holiday');
        }
    }
```

Its my first time trying CI, so please i need your help.

Comment: is this solved ??

Comment: @AbdullaNilam not yet, any sugestion?

Answer (score 0):

On `HitungCuti()` method, you are counting all of the employee holiday data. You need to limit the selection only for the submitted employee data :

```
public function HitungCuti($data)
{       
    $this->db->select('holID');
    $totalhol = $this->db->get_where('tabel_cuti', array('holEmpId' => $data['holEmpId'])); // only search for the specified employee ID

    return $totalhol;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't really read the whole questions thoroughly previously, I've updated my answer, I removed the `count..as`, `join` and `group_by` because it's unnecessary